# how to call all test in one folder using jest pattern matching?

Tags: node.js, regex, jestjs

I have my regular unit tests in folders with my services

Now I created new folder called `integration/` and inside this folder all my tests look like `anotherFolder/testSomeApi.integration.js`

I did this, so that when I call `node jest`, it runs all the unit tests but not the integration tests. I want to call integration tests from my docker container with separate command

How can I call something like `jest *integration.js` so that all tests in integration folder with extension `integration.js` gets called?

Comment: Perhaps `jest ".*integration\.js"`

Comment: Pattern: .*integration\.js - 0 matches

Comment: output from running your command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did

`jest  "(/integration/.*|\\.(integration))\\.(js)$"`

Answer (score 6):

```
jest --testPathPattern=".*/folderName/.*.spec.ts"
```

is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your *integration* folder create a config file for jest, e.g. **jest-integration.json**

```
{
    "rootDir": ".",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testRegex": ".integration.js$",
}
```

Now you can run jest from your project root like so:

`jest --config ./integration/jest-integration.json`

You could save this line as an NPM script in your *package.json* and use it like

`npm run test:integration`.